# Hide control in Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using label control in form designing.But i want to hide that particular label control on page load.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   Label10.Visible = False
End Sub
```

What should i do? I'm new to vb.net.

Comment: Please show us the aspx markup.

Comment: it is working fine...some thing is going wrong with work aspx code that cause this issue....as i suppose...

Comment: If you want to hide the label, your code already does it. However, doing so seems (on the face of it) pointless in having the label in the first place. You need to provide more information (and code) to explain exactly what you are trying to do, in what situation, and to what end

Comment: @AlphaMale: Why have you added that semicolon, this is VB.NET not C#

Comment: @AlphaMale, it's VB.NET, not C#

Comment: you can set the visible property to false in its designer also.

Comment: Maybe i've edited your question wrong, you've written that _"my code(writing this code in page load)
    -------
    `label10.visible=false`"_. Is the code in Page_Load rewritten correctly from me?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the visibility property within the aspx code rather than within the load event, this may solve your issue.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblValidation" runat="server" BackColor="Red" 
                    Text="Please fill in all of the date fields below to proceed" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

Hope this helps!